# I keep getting the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on line 9 error

Tags: python

In Line 9 I keep getting the error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on line 9

```
a = [[34, 38, 50, 44, 39],
              [42, 36, 40, 43, 44],
              [24, 31 ,46 ,40 ,45],
              [43, 47, 35, 31, 26],
              [37, 28, 20, 36, 50]]

sum_arr = 0  
for i in range(0, len(a)):    
    for i in int(sum_arr):
            sum_arr= sum_arr + a[i]
def mean_arr(arr_arg):
    count_arr = 0
    for row in arr_arg:
        for elem in row:
            count_arr += 1
            sum_arr += elem
    res = sum_arr / count_arr
    return res
print ("Sum of all values: "+ str(sum_arr))

print ("Average of all values: "+ str(mean_arr(a)))
```

Comment: Well, yes, you keep getting the error because `for i in int(sum_arr):` keeps not making sense. What do you *expect* it to do? What overall problem are you trying to solve? It seems like it has something to do with using a `for` loop to iterate over a nested list. Did you try putting `python iterate over nested list` into a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate through an integer. Instead try this.

```
for i in range(sum_arr):
```

Here's an example of what range is.

```
range(10)
```

returns us

```
range(0, 10)
```

and

```
list(range(0,10))
```

returns us

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```